# Angular q all dynamic results

Tags: javascript, angularjs, promise

I need to wait for two promises to resolve before doing something.The problem is that sometimes I can have only one promise to send based on what the client want, and I need to count on the results that comes from this $q.all. How can I dynamically define the vars?

```
  var makePurchaseToResolve = [];

    if( CartService.items.draws.length ) {
      var drawOrder = {};
      drawOrder.price = $scope.getTotal();
      drawOrder.paymentMethodId = $scope.payment.paymetMethodId;
      drawOrder.orderItems = CartService.items.draws;
      drawOrder.payFromBalance = false;
      makePurchaseToResolve.push(DrawService.makePurchase(drawOrder));
    }

    if( CartService.items.hunters.length ) {
      var hunterOrder = {};
      hunterOrder.paymentMethodId = $scope.payment.paymetMethodId;
      hunterOrder.orderItems = CartService.items.hunters;
      makePurchaseToResolve.push(HunterService.makePurchase(hunterOrder));      
    }


$q.all(makePurchaseToResolve).then(function( res ) {
     $q.all([HunterService.getPurchase(res[0].data.data),DrawService.getPurchase(res.data.data)]).then(function() {

            //here is the problem, because i dont know if i have the two promises to resolve or only one

            $scope.hunters = res[0].data.data[0];
            $scope.drawOrder = res[1].data.data;          
          })
}
```

Comment: Is it always 1 or 2?

Comment: No, in the future it will be more. I need it to be flexible.

Comment: Yes how this works that i need first make order and then get the id back and then create new post request to get the order.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A little known fact is that `$q.all` can also take an object rather than an array which can simplify your life in this case:

```
var purchases = {}; // an object rather than an array for named properties

if( CartService.items.draws.length ) {
  //...
  purchases.drawOrder = DrawService.makePurchase(drawOrder); // named assign
}

if( CartService.items.hunters.length ) {
  //...
  purchases.hunters = HunterService.makePurchase(hunterOrder);      
}

// any more additions to the objects here..

$q.all(purchases).then(function(resolved){
    // resolve anything further you need
    $scope.purchases = resolved; // Add $scope.purchases.hunters etc 
});
```

The promises are resolved in an object so they're named, instead of having an array you get a resolved object with properties so instead of doing arr[0] which might be out of order you'd do resolved.hunters or resolved.drawOrder. This solution just nests into $scope one level and does it automatically.

Comment: `resolved` in this case is the resolution value of `makePurchase` - I have omitted the `getPurchase` calls from this solution (put them in a comment) since they're irrelevant to the _idea_ here. You need to add them in your own code.

Comment: Yes but how i know which promise is resolved and assign the correct values to the correct $scope vars?

Comment: @JsIsAwesome because they resolved in an object so they're named, instead of having an array you get a resolved object with properties so instead of doing `arr[0]` which might be out of order you'd do `resolved.hunters` or `resolved.drawOrder`. This solution just nests into `$scope` one level and does it automatically.

Comment: Cool, i see it in the console. Thats was very very helpfull, thanks!!

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum, you can actually keep the order with `$q.all([null, noNullPromise])`

Comment: Yes but that's just doing the same thing in a less clear way that still assigns properties to the scope (thus triggers wathers) to be fair.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum, agreed - but it's an alternative when naming is not an option.

Answer (score 0):

You can also keep the order of the promises, if you'd like, and pass in `null` for those that were not applied based on your condition.

This is an alternative for when your service gets a dynamic number of purchase requests from the caller and naming is not an option.

```
$q.all([null, huntersOrderPromise])
     .then(function(data){
       $scope.drawOrder = data[0]; // will be null
       $scope.hunterOrder = data[1];
     });
```